# PHP Change the value of an arrays element in this case

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to change the value of the first element in the array, which initially starts out as a blank, and then, depending on the error, will be set to 'Success' or 'False'.

But what is the correct way to do this? What I'm trying, does not seem to work.

```
$arr['ERR'] = '';
$arr['ERR'] .= '<i>Error 1</i>,';
$arr['ERR'] .= '<i>Error 2</i>,';
$arr['ERR'] .= '<i>Error 3</i>,';
$arr['ERR'] .= '<i>Error 4</i>,';
```

$errors = 1;

```
$arr['ERR'][0] = ($errors == 0 ? 'Success' : 'There were errors with your data!');

print_r($arr);
```

print_r gives me:

```
Array ( [ERR] =>
Fi>Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
Error 4
)
```

PS: I need that particular element right at the top.

What I'm hoping to achieve is:

`Array ( [ERR] => There were errors with your data,Error 1,Error 2,Error 3,Error 4, )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to concatenate on to the beginning of your error string by the looks of it:

```
$arr['ERR'] = ($errors == 0 ? 'Success' : 'There were errors with your data, ' . $arr['ERR']);
```

Dumped:

> Array ( [ERR] => There were errors with your data, Error 1,Error 2,Error 3,Error 4, )

Answer (score 0):

On the first line initialize the `$arr['ERR']` variable with 'There were errors with your data: '

Comment: This is what would give you exactly the answer you expect.

Answer (score 0):

var_dumping your code right now produces this array

```
array(1) { ["ERR"]=> string(60) "Error 1,Error 2,Error 3,Error 4," }
```

Doing what you're doing right now won't work as there's only one array entry. You could try create an array with all the entries and concatenate all of them with a `foreach` loop afterwards or use `array_unshift()` to prepend to the array.

i.e.

```
$arr = array('',
             '<i>Error 1</i>,',
             '<i>Error 2</i>,',
             '<i>Error 3</i>,',
             '<i>Error 4</i>');

if(error_logic_here) {
    array_unshift($arr, "error");
}
```

Would produce:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "error" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(15) "Error 1," [3]=> string(15) "Error 2," [4]=> string(15) "Error 3," [5]=> string(14) "Error 4" }
```

Which you can then concatenate like so:

```
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $str .= $value;
}
```

Which would produce:

```
string(64) "errorError 1,Error 2,Error 3,Error 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
   $arr['ERR'][0]= '<i>Error 1</i>,';
    $arr['ERR'][1]= '<i>Error 2</i>,';
    $arr['ERR'][2]= '<i>Error 3</i>,';
    $arr['ERR'][3]= '<i>Error 4</i>,';

    $errors = 1;

    $arr['ERR'][0] = ($errors == 0) ?'Success':'There were errors with your data!';

    print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach, this might work good for you:

```
$errors = 1;
$arr = array();
$arr['ERR'][] = '';
$arr['ERR'][] .= '<i>Error 1</i>,';
$arr['ERR'][] .= '<i>Error 2</i>,';
$arr['ERR'][] .= '<i>Error 3</i>,';
$arr['ERR'][] .= '<i>Error 4</i>,';

$arr['ERR'][0] = ($errors == 0 ? 'Success' : 'There were errors with your data!');
print_r($arr);
```

Hope it solves your problem.